# Literature for the Big-M constraint method

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, big-m

I've come across the possibility of introducing binary variables in linear programming with the Big-M method here several times now. Here is an example:

\begin{align}
&(1-x_{i})\le \sum_i y_i\\
&M\cdot (1-x_{i})\ge \sum_i y_i
\end{align}

However, when I look up Big-M, I only find literature and works on the Big-M method for solving LPs. Is there also literature on the Big-M method for constraints?

Comment: What do you mean with Big-M for constraints? Aren't the two inequalities you mention constraints?

Answer (score 1):

It's covered in a lot of textbooks. For instance, chapter 9 ("Building Integer Programming Models I") in the fourth edition of the excellent book "Model Building in Mathematical Programming" by H. Paul Williams has a big-M constraint containing an indicator variable in the very first formula.

Rather than searching "big M", you might want to search "indicator variable".